# Check for a new version of a script from within the script

Tags: python, python-2.7, updates

Suppose I have constantly enabled script (a telegram bot) on a remote server. Obviously, logging into the server whenever I want to update the script is cumbersome.

Is there some way to check for a new version of the script (on GitHub, for example) and update it?

Comment: How do you run this script? On many platforms there is a background process monitor that automatically restarts killed scripts. The script or something else running on a system timer could check for updates and kill the script as needed.

Comment: @tdelaney I connect to the server through SSH and run python script.py, and I guess the server is some form of Linux. How can I download the new version and replace the old one with it?

Comment: assuming you have the script somewhere on github, you can either `wget <github_link> -O script.py && python script.py` or `wget <github_link> -O | python`